# OS color difference between interface builder and screenshot (simulator & device)

Tags: ios, xib, background-color

If I set the background color of the rootview  in interface builder I get a wrong bg color (differs from original value). If I set it programmatically the view has the correct bg color.
Is there anything I doesn't see?

I use XIB and no storyboards...

**EDIT (A more detailed description of the scenario and the problem):**

I define my page (view) in the interfacebuilder and set a background color of RGB (100, 100, 100).

[image]

In my AppDelegate I have the following code:

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window = window;

IndexViewController *indexViewController = [[IndexViewController alloc] init];

self.viewController = indexViewController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

If I then take a screenshot of the app I get a background color of RGB (81, 81, 81).

The IndexViewController does nothing. When set the background color of the root view of the view controller in the viewDidLoad method the resulting color is correct.

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHex:@"#646464" alpha:1.0]];
```

I tried to solve the problem by myself for a couple of hours but I am not so experienced in ios development. Hope someone can help!

**SOLUTION:**

1. Go to system preferences -> displays -> Colors and select the
   "Generic RGB"
2. In the color picker in the interfacebuilder click the
   gear-wheel next to drop-down (RGB Sliders) and select "Generic RGB"

Attention! If you enter the rgb values dont take the focus to the "Hex Color #" input. As soon as this happens, the color picker will reset the color profile to "sRGB ...". This seems to be a bug!?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what colors you are using in the XIB and programmatically?

Comment: Its clear that there is something we don't see..... any example from you, anything we can use to give you help on a problem which looks more like you didn't spend too much time on this problem to really solve it by yourself

Comment: Click that wheel next to the dropdown and select generic rgb.

Comment: Thanks Filip. I found the same soultion in the mean time.

Comment: @Dan Come on, this site is not a forum and has a specific format! No "solved" in the title. It's questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your function : 
    [UIColor colorWithHex:@"#646464" alpha:1.0]
is creating that difference.

Try using this :

```
- (UIColor *)colorFromRGBHexString:(NSString *)colorString {
if(colorString.length == 7) {
    const char *colorUTF8String = [colorString UTF8String];
    int r, g, b;
    sscanf(colorUTF8String, "#%2x%2x%2x", &r, &g, &b);
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(r / 255.0) green:(g / 255.0) blue:(b / 255.0) alpha:1.0];
}    
return nil;
}
```

Comment: No this is not the problem since if I set the color with this method I get the correct result. Please see my solution above.

Comment: Which device you are using for taking snapshot ? or using simulator ?